# Mapreduce job not launching when running hive query with where clause

Tags: hive

I am using apache-hive-1.2.2 on Hadoop 2.6.0. When am running a hive query with where clause it is giving results immediately without launching any MapReduce job. I'm not sure what is happening. Table has over 100k records.

Comment: Can you provide sample query and its console output?

Comment: i created emp table with 11 columns and the table is having 20 rows ..

Comment: when i fire select * from emp query its giving results immediately with out launching any mapreduce job which is expected.

Comment: But when i fire select first_name,last_name from emp; which is also giving the results immediately with out running any mapreduce job.I tried loading 100 rows into the emp table but the same result with the second query.

Comment: I tested the same table with same data on hive-0.11 version..for first query i.e select * from emp its giving results immeditely with out MR job...But launching the MR job for second query even with 20rows of data which is expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am quoting this from [Hive Documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties)

> hive.fetch.task.conversion
>
> Some select queries can be converted to a single FETCH task,
> minimizing latency. Currently the query should be single sourced not
> having any subquery and should not have any aggregations or distincts
> (which incur RS – ReduceSinkOperator, requiring a MapReduce task),
> lateral views and joins.

Any type of the sort of aggregation like max or min or count is going to require a MapReduce job. So it depends on your data-set you have.

```
select * from tablename;
```

It just reads raw data from files in HDFS, so it is much faster without MapReduce and it doesn't need MR.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the the property "hive.fetch.task.conversion". The default value is set to "more" (Hive 2.1.0) and results in Hive trying to go straight at the data by launching a single Fetch task instead of a Map Reduce job wherever possible.

This behaviour however might not be desirable in case you have a huge table (say 500 GB+) as it would cause a single thread to be launched instead of multiple threads as happens in the case of a Map Reduce job.
You can set this property to "minimal" or "none" in hive-site.xml to bypass the behaviour.